Switch Nodes for Text Lines Blender 4.2.3 LTS and 3.5
I have followed Khamurai's instructions for using SWITCH Nodes in Text Lines
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_PPpuonOz3Y
and was able to get it right up to 3 text lines only.  I have set up my Geometry Nodes for 7 text lines at least.  Why can't I get my text lines right on the 4th and beyond ?
Also, I wasn't able to wrap my head around the SWITCH node in the Modifier view / window which is the reason I reverted back to using 3.5 for this SWITCH NODE use.
Intended use for this is for captions using CUSTOM designed TEXTS
I know this might be tedious but I'm after the UNIQUeNESS, and getting to know Geometry nodes a bit more.
Thanks in Advance for any help coming my way.
Here's my file in Google Drive:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FZRTlft4mjiXBwOUYCUK-7QvqrhTVY4J/view?usp=sharing

Please do not use external resources for uploading files, go to this site: https://blend-exchange.com and follow the instructions there to edit your file into your question. Also don't make users having to follow external links and trying to figure out everything on their, give at least one or more screenshots of what you did or what the problem is.

First of all, the way you have set this up you will always see only one text - because your keyframes change the first, second, third Switch nodes from False to True etc., but your 4th Switch is always True. The settings of the previous switches will only show if the 4th is set to False.
More than that, if you want to have 7 text strings: in the current file as it is, there are no keyframes to change the 5th and 6th Switch to True, so of course you will never see any of those other text strings if you do not switch them on. With this setup, choosing strings works like this: set that Switch to True which has the string you want to see in the True input and all other Switches to False (previous switches can be True, but for the sake of an easier overview it would be best to only have the desired one switched to True). If you want to see the very very first Switch node's False input, all have to be set to False.
Apart from all this what I mention above: sometimes it is better to do newer tutorials for current Blender versions. The one you've linked to is for 3.0, we now have 4.2.3 and there have been a lot of changes. Sure, to learn Geometry Nodes in general you can do older tutorials, but some of them do things very complicated which are much easier nowadays.
For example, a while ago Geometry Nodes got new kinds of Switch nodes added: the Menu Switch and the Index Switch. With the Index Switch you can set a specific type of data (in your case String) and change between different entries by changing the Index. This way you don't need multiple Switch nodes that you continuously change from True to False and back, you just animate the Index. The data can be written directly in fields of the node or be connected by inputs.


It's You again sensei !!!  I checked the Green Mark this time.

I got it to work up to the 5th text line this time.  Two more text lines to go.  This is in 3.5 by the way.  Will try this on 4.2.3LTS  since you mentioned it's way more easier than older versions.  I'm still doing the switching via the Modifier Properties in the LayOut Tab.  Is it still the same in 4.2.3LTS ?

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1m9fBc2gEyv5w8t9NFM8y4sQMRPL7mQXO?usp=sharing

Excuse me for awhile but gonna have dinner with wife and kids and binge watch the Korean series     Judge from Hell    with wifey

This is not a site for chats, you don't have to tell everything you're doing here.

I tried the new Index Switch and found it a big game changer.  Not confusing!!!  Easy to switch text lines !!!  But my next roadblock I need your help with is...  How do I increase the number of Indexes (Text Lines) from the usual 0-1   to  how you did it  0-6  or more... ?

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/12KigBRzGiDf-zSKt0bCqnSx2DO6SiFVP?usp=sharing

When you have String nodes you want to plug in the Index Switch node, just connect them to the next empty socket: add connection. Or if you want to have empty fields where you can enter text, go into the sidepanel (shortcut N) and with the Index Switch selected, go to the Node properties and click Add Item as often as you need: add new item. Another option would be to just plug a String node in an empty socket and then disconnect it again. I would recommend you do more tutorials, this is very basic stuff.

Used a single String Node to activate Index 2-7 and onwards !!!  Thank You so much for the very quick response.  This will help me a lot and make things easier.
